# Databar Appears only when cell edit made

Tags: excel-2010, epplus

I have exported data from datagridview to excelsheet using epplus library

```
For i = 0 To Analysis.dgv1.Columns.Count - 1
     worksheet1.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = Analysis.dgv1.Columns(i).HeaderText
Next
For i = 0 To Analysis.dgv1.Rows.Count - 1
    For j = 0 To Analysis.dgv1.Columns.Count - 1
         worksheet1.Cells(i + 2, j + 1).Value = Analysis.dgv1.Rows.Item(i).Cells(j).Value
    Next
Next

Using range = worksheet1.Cells(2, 4, Analysis.dgv1.RowCount, 5)
      range.Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0"
End Using
```

Column 4,5 is numeric column i have added databar to the excelsheet using

```
Using range = worksheet1.Cells(2, 4, Analysis.dgv1.RowCount, 5)
      range.ConditionalFormatting.AddDatabar(System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen)
End Using
```

In exported excelsheet all data shows fine but, databars only appears when cell edit made 
here is screenshot of image [image]

84,83 Are cell where i entered in edit mode other are un touched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because databar needs numeric value and here you are entering number as string try converting it to number before insert